# How can i loop through result from mysql query?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have two tables one for properties and one for users. and I wanna generate a new table that contains propertyID with user name, So i want to loop through the users ids from the properties table then do a query to get the name and assign it to the propertyID like the final table.

Properties

```
| propertyID | userID |
|------------|--------|
| 123        | 2      |
| 453        | 4      |
| 345        | 6      |
| 378        | 6      |
```

Users

```
| userID | name  |
|--------|-------|
| 2      | zeyad |
| 4      | test  |
| 6      | elan  |
```

Desired Table

```
| propertyID | name  |
|------------|-------|
| 123        | zeyad |
```

How can i do this?

Comment: With an inner join..

Comment: Why user 2 is returned whereas users 4 and 6 are ignored?

Comment: Thanks @P.Salmon will try it.

Comment: As an example @Akina

Comment: Example output must match example data fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just like this

```
CREATE TABLE desiredTable AS
SELECT p.propertyID, u.name FROM Properties p
LEFT JOIN Users u
ON u.userID = p.userID
```

Careful to the column name you use ("name" is a SQL keyword, use username instead :))

Comment: `name` is a keyword, but it is not a _reserved_ keyword. One can use it as an identifier without delimiting it.